# High pitch sound when main floor bathroom shower is running

Tags: shower

There are 4 bathrooms in this house: 2 on second floor, 1 in the basement and 1 on the main floor. This house was built in 1996. All are stand up showers except for one bathroom located on the second floor.

Whenever the shower is running on the main floor, there is a high pitch sound that can only be heard on the second floor bathroom, which is located directly above the main floor bathroom. I don't hear this high pitch sound when flushing toilet or using the tap water in the main floor bathroom.

I did some googling and it seems like it may have something to do with a Pressure Water Regulator. However, I don't hear this high pitch sound when anything else is running, except for the aforementioned main floor shower. This leads me to believe that maybe the cause is the shower head?

I checked around the main water shut off and did not see a Pressure Water Regulator. I think this is because it wasn't a requirement in 1996?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Trying to see if this is a professional plumber type of thing or something I can do myself. Thanks.

Comment: Try adjusting the flow to the shower. If that changes the pitch it is the valve. Try both hot and cold.

Answer (score 1):

We used to have a water saving shower head that pulled air into the shower stream. Awful thing; made a high pitched sound when the shower was running. If the shower heads are replaceable, I'd try swapping two and see if the noise moves with the shower head. A split pipe or shower head could cause the same. I'd have thought that this would be more noticeable in the same bathroom as the running shower but the principle still stands, swap parts and see if the sound moves. Try both hot and cold.

The water running to waste sometimes causes a bit of a vacuum and may cause it to suck in air. You may have an air admittance valve (AAV) on your waste pipe that lets air into the drain pipework, or the vacuum may try and suck air through sink / shower wastes. Both can oscillate and produce noise. Run the shower, and listen to the drains on the 2nd floor to see if it's the drains that are noisy. You can also try putting the sink plugs in / out to see if it makes a difference.

If you have a hot water cylinder or tank on the top floor, the noise might simply be that refilling; especially if the noise continues for a while after turning the shower off.

If you have isolation valves on your showers / sinks etc you could try isolating all of the other fixings to see if the sound goes away. It probably won't make a difference but it just reduces the amount of pipework to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a shower valve issue. If it's a recent model, you should be able to find and order the cartridge.